# Injection tokens in angular

Tags: angular

I understand to an extent as to what injection tokens are. I just couldn't get my mind around the use cases where we can use it. I have seen some examples where the tokens are used to manage API paths and some other config details. My doubt is it really a best practice to use injection tokens and if so, what would be the use cases for it ?

Answer (score 1):

TLTR: injection tokens provide a way to pass values into angular DI with the power of being able to change them based on the "context". Take a look at the example below!

Let's say we have an app that needs to generate an absolute url in an angular component, and this app works both on the server and on the client (it then uses server side rendering).

On the client, the app knows the base href where it is but not on the server. In this case an injection token would be useful: we want to provide a base href when the app is on the server, but we don't need it on the client.

Here's an example of the code on the server module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'https://michelepatrassi.io'},
  ]
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

with the APP_BASE_HREF injection token, the angular app on the server now has what it needs to generate absolute url by using a function like [prepareExternalUrl](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#prepareExternalUrl) (which uses APP_BASE_HREF to create the url, check the docs).

When the application renders on the client, `APP_BASE_HREF` should be resetted to an empty string to don't prepend it twice. This can be easily done by adding this in the providers of the `app.module`

```
...

{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: ''}

...
```